# How to detect mouse moving while left button down?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, mouse

I would like to detect mouse movement while the left button is pressed.

I'm simply creating a drawing application. I can detect mouse movement without any mouse being pressed. But I want to detect it WITH left mouse pressed.

I don't think there's a listener for this. So, what is the idea to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is mouseDragged method in MouseMotionListener...check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) out for more details...

Comment: @Stephen P, I accidently upvoted your comment because I misread it. There is absolutely no need to summarize the API here. Its a waste of time as that is what the API is for. All the OP needed was to be pointed in the right direction. In fact, just mentioning the class and method is a great answer. People should always have access to the API to read it for the details.

Comment: @camickr It is good practice to keep answers evergreen. This means limiting links, as one day they may break and the whole answer will be moot. Overall, this should have been a comment, not an answer. It is the "Stack way" to make answers be explanations, not links to reference sites and API.

Comment: @CoryB, I think I've been doing this a little longer than you have. `This means limiting links,` - that is what my comment suggested. There was no need to include the link.

Comment: @camickr Ah, I see what your saying now. Your first comment is a bit confusing. Thank you for the clarification. Seeing as how your comment was 4 years old, I was more commenting for new people who may read this "correct" answer in the future and learn bad practice. (Also, using seniority is a logical fallacy and isn't welcoming to new people. Though I am flattered that you took the time to look me up and do the math. Stay classy, sugar.)

Comment: The API clearly does not discuss button clicks or the button state while moving. This is a misleading answer.

Answer (score 16):

```
component.addmouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
       if ( SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
         // do your stuff here
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see the need to spoon feed code like this. The OP just wnated to be pointed in the right direction as you can tell by the answer that was accepted. The OP can ask for more help if he needs it.

Comment: Interesting that the answer that didn't mention how to figure out which button was pressed was accepted, when the question specified the *left* mouse button is needed.   I found this question via search, and I really do need it to be the *left* mouse button as specified in the question, so I'm upvoting this answer (although isLeftMouseButton is misspelled as of this writing)

Answer (score 2):

In your MouseMotionListener you can check for this using:

```
SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me.getPoint())
```

and you would listen for the mouseDragged event.

Comment: you've got it mostly here, but I just expanded in my answer

Comment: @DonHatch, good catch. I was going to say good "point", but that would be wrong :) I'll leave the code as is just so people can get the joke (since they will probably use Jeffs answer anyway).

Answer (score -1):

I think there might be some sort of mouse drag listener, but if not...

Capture the mouse button down and up events.  In those events, set a boolean such as `leftButtonIsDown = true` (unless there's already some easy way to query that) and then in the mouse movement events use a block like `if (leftButtonIsDown)`